# PHP - Hit counter textfile reset

Tags: php, web, refresh, hitcounter

I have an issue with my non-unique hit counter.

The script is as below:

```
$filename = 'counter.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $current_value = file_get_contents($filename);
} else {
    $current_value = 0;
}
$current_value++;
file_put_contents($filename, $current_value);
```

When I'm refreshing my website very often (like 10 times per second or even faster), the value in the text file are getting reset to 0.

Any guess for fixing this issue?

Comment: tried rapid firing the (`F5`), seems to work fine. maybe a permission issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty poor way to maintain a counter, but your problem is probably that when you fire multiple requests at the site, one of the calls to `file_exists()` is getting a false because one of the other processes is removing and recreating the file.

If you want this to work consistantly you are going to have to lock the file between read and write [See flock on php manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.flock.php)

Of course without the file lock you would also be getting incorrect counts anyway, when 2 processes manage to read the same value from the file.

Locking the file would also potentially slow your system down as 2 or more processes queue for access to the file.

It would probably be a better idea to store your counter in a database, as they are designed for coping with this kind of quick fire access and ensuring every process is properly queued and released.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you add a check if file_get_contents isn't returning false?

```
$value = file_get_contents($filename);
if($value !== false)
{
    $current_value = $value
}
```